# llamar form desde pyw

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

estoy desarrollando una ventana de inicio de sesión pero quiero abrirla desde otro archivo, el primer archivo es extensión .py  tiene el nombre de loginven.py que contiene la estructura de la ventana, elaborada con pyqt5 y tiene el siguiente código, la idea es tener un archivo con la estructura de la ventana y tener otro archivo donde se haga la programacion del comportamiento de los controles que estan en la ventana:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
 
 
 class Ui_Dialog(object):
     def setupUi(self, Dialog):
         Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
         Dialog.resize(379, 210)
         icon = QtGui.QIcon()
         icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../ventanas/recursos/iconoventana.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
         Dialog.setWindowIcon(icon)
         self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
         self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 20, 231, 31))
         font = QtGui.QFont()
         font.setFamily("Arial Black")
         font.setPointSize(16)
         font.setBold(True)
         font.setWeight(75)
         self.label.setFont(font)
         self.label.setObjectName("label")
         self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
         self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 151, 31))
         font = QtGui.QFont()
         font.setPointSize(12)
         self.label_2.setFont(font)
         self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
         self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
         self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 171, 31))
         font = QtGui.QFont()
         font.setPointSize(12)
         self.label_3.setFont(font)
         self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
         self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
         self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 170, 75, 23))
         icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
         icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../ventanas/recursos/aceptar.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
         self.pushButton.setIcon(icon1)
         self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
         self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
         self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 170, 75, 23))
         icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
         icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../ventanas/recursos/cancelar.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
         self.pushButton_2.setIcon(icon2)
         self.pushButton_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(16, 16))
         self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
         self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
         self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 80, 161, 20))
         self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
         self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
         self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 120, 161, 20))
         self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
 
         self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
         QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
 
     def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
         _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
         Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Sistema de Gestion de Condominio"))
         self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Ingreso de Usuarios"))
         self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Ingrese su Usuario:"))
         self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Ingrese su Contraseña:"))
         self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Aceptar"))
         self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Salir"))
 
 if __name__ == "__main__":
     import sys
     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
     Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
     ui = Ui_Dialog()
     ui.setupUi(Dialog)
     Dialog.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
    y el otro archivo es el llamará a esa ventana, tiene extension .pyw y tiene el nombre de logincod.pyw el siguiente codigo:
```

```
  import sys
  from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
  from pyQt5 import uic
  from loginven import *
  
  class MiFormulario(QtGui.QDialog):
      def __init__(self, parent=None):
          QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
          self.ui = MiFormulario()
          self.ui.setupUi(self)
          
          
          
          
          
  if __name__ == "__main__":
      import sys
      app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
      Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
      ui = Ui_Dialog()
      ui.setupUi(Dialog)
      Dialog.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

pero al hacerle doble click no abre la ventana,lo que deseo es hacer un archivo que contenga la estructura de la ventana y hacer otro archivo con la programacion de los controles de la ventana,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intentalo:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
#from pyQt5 import uic

#from loginven import Ui_Dialog
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(379, 210)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../ventanas/recursos/iconoventana.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Dialog.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 20, 231, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 151, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 171, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 170, 75, 23))
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../ventanas/recursos/aceptar.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton.setIcon(icon1)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 170, 75, 23))
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../ventanas/recursos/cancelar.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton_2.setIcon(icon2)
        self.pushButton_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(16, 16))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 80, 161, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 120, 161, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
 
    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Sistema de Gestion de Condominio"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Ingreso de Usuarios"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Ingrese su Usuario:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Ingrese su Contraseña:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Aceptar"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Salir"))

  
#class MiFormulario(QtGui.QDialog):
class MiFormulario(QtWidgets.QDialog):                            # QtWidgets
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
#        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        super(MiFormulario, self).__init__(parent)                # +
        
#        self.ui = MiFormulario()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()                                     # +
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clickAceptar)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.close)
        
    def clickAceptar(self):
        print("clicked button 'Aceptar'")    
        print(f"Ingrese su Usuario    : {self.ui.lineEdit.text()}")  
        print(f"Ingrese su Contraseña:: {self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()}")
          
          
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
#    ui = Ui_Dialog()
#    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
#    Dialog.show()
    
    w = MiFormulario()                            # +++
    w.show()                                      # +++
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Update**

> pero todo eso va en un solo archivo? lo que deseo es un archivo que es la estructura de la ventana y otro archivo que la llame y controle los eventos de los botones del formulario

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
#from pyQt5 import uic

from loginven import Ui_Dialog                                    # +

  
#class MiFormulario(QtGui.QDialog):
class MiFormulario(QtWidgets.QDialog):                            # QtWidgets
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
#        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        super(MiFormulario, self).__init__(parent)                # +
        
#        self.ui = MiFormulario()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()                                     # +
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clickAceptar)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.close)
        
    def clickAceptar(self):
        print("clicked button 'Aceptar'")    
        print(f"Ingrese su Usuario    : {self.ui.lineEdit.text()}")  
        print(f"Ingrese su Contraseña:: {self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()}")
          
          
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   
    w = MiFormulario()                            # +++
    w.show()                                      # +++
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**loginven.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(379, 210)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../ventanas/recursos/iconoventana.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Dialog.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 20, 231, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 151, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 171, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 170, 75, 23))
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../ventanas/recursos/aceptar.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton.setIcon(icon1)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 170, 75, 23))
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../ventanas/recursos/cancelar.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton_2.setIcon(icon2)
        self.pushButton_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(16, 16))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 80, 161, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 120, 161, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
 
    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Sistema de Gestion de Condominio"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Ingreso de Usuarios"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Ingrese su Usuario:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Ingrese su Contraseña:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Aceptar"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Salir"))
```

Comment: pero todo eso va en un solo archivo? lo que deseo es un archivo que es la estructura de la ventana y otro archivo que la llame y controle los eventos de los botones del formulario

Comment: @MarcoSalazar see update